# how to fix update error

Tags: yii

i want to update all row's alternativegroups with $id value.

the action getting error: coldchain can not be null.

when i search the db for pk = $a, It's coldchain value is boolen(false). and db is postgresql

how can i set $q->attributes without posting other values?

```
public function actionUpdate($id){

    if (isset($_POST['forms'])){

        $arr = explode(',', $_POST['forms']);

        foreach ($arr as $a){

            $q = MedicineDrugform::model()->findbypk($a);
            $q->alternativegroup = $id;
            if ($q->save()){
                echo $q->id."q saved <br />";
            }
            else {
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($q->getErrors());
            }

            die();

            $qu = MedicineDrugformUpdate::model()->findbyattributes(array('drug_form_id'=>$a));
            $quu = MedicineDrugformUpdate::model()->findbypk($qu->id);
            $quu->alternativegroup = $id;
            if ($quu->save()){
                echo $quu->id."qu saved <br />";
            }


        }
        die();
        $this->render('/site/messages', array('message'=>'formsaved'));

    }

    $this->render('add', array('id'=>$id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it cant find the corresponding record for

```
$q = MedicineDrugform::model()->findbypk($a);
```